# Error while staring spring boot Kafka project

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Error getting when starting spring boot kafka project.

spring boot : 2.1.2.RELEASE
Spring kafka version : 2.2.5.RELEASE

Consumer cannot be configured for auto commit for ackMode MANUAL_IMMEDIATE

Consumer config

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroup);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return props;
}
```

Kafka Listener container factory

```
@Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    factory.setRecoveryCallback(context -> {
        log.error("Maximum retry policy has been reached {}", context.getAttribute("record"));
        Acknowledgment ack = (Acknowledgment) context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT);
        ack.acknowledge();
        return null;
    });
    factory.setConcurrency(Integer.parseInt(kafkaConcurrency));
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Exception 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Consumer cannot be configured for auto commit for ackMode MANUAL_IMMEDIATE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` ack mode (for any manual mode, essentilly), the `ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG` consumer property must be turned off.

That's the reason of that exception.

I guess you can just don't use a `spring.kafka.consumer.enableAutoCommit` in your `application.properties`.

Comment: Still getting the same error..It worked thanks i have update my consumer config..Thank a lot

Comment: Time to share a simple project to let us to reproduce and play with?

Comment: Yes Please share i wanted to know how does retry config and acknowledge are handle..

Comment: No, you share your problem about `autoCommit`. The retry and acknowledge is fully different story and deserves its own SO thread. Thank you for understanding!

Comment: This part was done..I have one more doubt 
 I am reading a book in which it was written when you successfully consume message in that case you perform asyncCommit() that handle by Kafka itself..and in case of exception we need to perform syncCommit() ..But when i using spring retry in that case when i perform acknowledge it perform asyncCommit()..

Comment: Not sure in your last sentence. Please, really start a new SO thread with much more info.